# Posting a todo to my database - It works with Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to write the code for my todo app in React. I can't seem to add a new todo to the database with the handleSubmit function. It does seem to work (todo gets added) when I use Postman, but for some sort of reason it doesn't work when I try entering a todo in the input field on my app and submit it. Anyone that can see what's wrong?

---

**Todo.js component - FRONT-END**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Todo.css'  
import Todoitem from '../components/Todoitem'
import axios from 'axios'
import qs from "qs"
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"

class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            title:"",
            todos:[]
        }
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/todo`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let todolist = response.data;
            this.setState({todos:todolist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error when getting the todos charles: ",error)
        })
    }

handleChange(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        let name = event.target.name
        let value = event.target.value
        this.setState({
            [name]:value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/todo`,
            data: qs.stringify({title: this.state.title}),
            headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DefaultLayout>
                <h1>To-do things for this app</h1>
                <h2 className="todotitle">Add your to-do here, Charles!</h2>
                <form className="todocontainer"> 
                    <div className="inputbuttonandfield">    
                        <div className="inputcontainer">
                            <div className="captionpart" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <label className="captionlabel" htmlFor="title">Add to-do:</label><br></br>
                                <input className="captionform" type="text" name="title" value={this.state.title} placeholder="Type your to-do here!" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button className="shootbutton">Add!</button>
                    </div>
                </form> 
                <div>

                {
                    this.state.todos.map((element,i) => (
                        <Todoitem key={i}/>
                    ))
                }

                </div>
                </DefaultLayout>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todo
```

---

**Todo - model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const todoSchema = new Schema({
    title: String
})

const Todo = mongoose.model("todos",todoSchema)

module.exports = Todo
```

---

**INDEX.js - backend**

```
//add to-do
router.post("/todo", (req,res) => {
  Todo
  .create({
    title: req.body.title
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Charles the post todo is working")
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Charles the post todo is NOT working")
    res.json(error)
  })
})

//request todos
router.get("/todo", (req,res) => {
  Todo
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is probably what is wrong `data: qs.stringify(this.state.title)`

You need to send data as plain object or as query string, like that

```
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred'
  },

  // or 

  data: 'Country=Brasil&City=Belo Horizonte'
```

Right now you sending something like that `data: 'Some title'`.

You probably forgot to wrap parameter into object `qs.stringify({title: this.state.title})`. Or just dump `x-www-form-urlencoded` and send it like plain object!

Comment: thanks a lot! Your point makes a lot of sense to me but unfortunately the todo is still not being added to my database. I updated the code above (added " qs.stringify({title: this.state.title})" - could you please please have another look?

Comment: anyone else could have a look at this please?

Comment: Does this controller `router.post("/todo", ...` works at all when you use it with React? What is `req.body.title` there?

Comment: I tried console logging req.body.title when using React, but it doesn't appear in the console when I submit a todo. I also get this error in the console (which I think is a different issue): Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Answer (score 0):

in back end you are dealing with json,
u need to change your data: qs.stringify({title: this.state.title}) to data: